# JQuery Appending a Comma to my TextArea

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to figure out this situation.

```
<textarea id="addinfo" name="addinfo"></textarea>

alert(f.addinfo);
```

If my input into the textarea is "hello", the alert says "hello,".
  If there is no input, the alert says ",".

What's going on?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like you may have two fields named addInfo, and youre getting a comma-delimited list of the values

Comment: I actually think this is what's happening here... When I store a default value to the textarea, say <textarea>Default</textarea>, If I input say, "Hello", I get "Hello,Default"

Comment: then it is because you don't use the addinfo.value  
and instead you get a list of all properties comma separated.

Comment: can you post more of your page? clearly thats not all the code on the page

Comment: I figured it out; it was two fields of the same name... I was using a plugin called Impromptu, and didn't realize I had created two of the same field!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to do the same thing you do, with **jQuery** included and I don't seem to have this problem. Maybe your problem is that you don't get the DOMElement correctly.

Try **document.getElementById('addinfo')**

And another problem could be that you don't use **addinfo.value** you just use **addinfo which is a DOMElement not the string from the textarea**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I recreated a page like you have it,

except i used the **addinfo.value**

works fine like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testing textarea value</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
    </script>
    <script language="javascript">
        function test(){
            alert(f.addinfo.value);
        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="f" name="f">
        <textarea id="addinfo" name="addinfo"></textarea>
        <a href="javascript:test()">test click</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted for the effort, I didn't provide much code to make an accurate diagnosis, turns out to be arnie's answer.